# Является ли переменная Answer в данном случае общей для всех запросов от любых устройств?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, http

К примеру имеется следующая серверная программа, которая слушает порт и ожидает поступления новых данных от клиентов:
Итак, если существует 3 разных клиента, которые отправили на данный порт запрос с данными 1,2 и 3 в порядке возрастания. (Единицу отправляет первый пользователь, двойку - второй, а тройку - третий), тогда на момент вывода в третий раз console.log мы получим в консоле число 3 или же 123 ???

```
let http = require("http");
let Answer = ""; // Глобальная ли эта переменная ?

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    req.on("data", data => {
        Answer += data.toString();
        console.log(Answer);
    }


    res.end("");
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: И что мешает проверить это самому?

Comment: Просто есть ряд вопросов, которые хотелось бы решить без проверки в то время как занимаюсь другими вопросами... Некоторые моменты даже на тестах нельзя проверить. Например я не понимаю на сервере можно использовать синхронные функции или же они будут блокировать других клиентов... Это даже момент поважнее будет, надо было этот вопрос задать... Из этого уже я бы мог отталкиваться, переписывать ли мне серверную часть в асинхронный вариант или же нет а если переписывать, то как можно вернуть ответ если функция отправлена в свободное плавание...

Comment: Например поместив res.end в колбэк асинхронной функции я получаю ошибку того, что ответ получается раньше чем закрывается поток. по всей видимости колбэк срабатывает по факту завершения чтения или записи но не по факту закрытия потока... эх вот же гемор... Почему нельзя было сделать низкоуровневую работу с потоками и файлами как на с++ например... Еще и файл надо как то проверить на предмет того, не записывается ли он в данный момент, так как записывать могут 2 устройства одновременно а это не хорошо...

Comment: *Например я не понимаю на сервере можно использовать синхронные функции или же они будут блокировать других клиентов* - синхронные функции будут блокировать других клиентов.

Comment: _Например поместив res.end в колбэк асинхронной функции я получаю ошибку_ - если ты помещаешь, как в своих предыдущих вопросах - ничего удивительного, так как у тебя два `res.end` один из которых выполняется сразу же.

Comment: Оу, вы открыли мне глаза. Теперь мне стало все понятно !!! Просто от души благодарю Stepan Kasyanenko и Grundy !!!